# R: How to change colnames on a dataframe called by a character vector?

Tags: r, get, character

I have a set of dataframes that i am struggling changing the colnames on

```
for(i in c("ML","HL","MSMS","PEP","MqNormHM","MixHM","RawHM","AbsHM","SepAbsHM")){
  j<-ifelse(i %in% c("ML","HL","MSMS","PEP","MqNormHM"),paste("Rel",i,sep=""),i)
  colnames(get(j))<-paste(i,colnames(get(j)),sep="")
}
```

Gives me:

```
Error in colnames(get(j)) <- paste(i, colnames(get(j)), sep = "") : 
  could not find function "get<-"
```

ML, HL etc. are individual dataframes of the following form:

```
> head(RelML)
          AA       BB       CC       DD       EE      LL      MM      NN
2684 0.19650       NA       NA       NA       NA      NA      NA      NA
4470      NA       NA       NA       NA       NA 0.35249      NA 0.35797
3619 0.22108 0.098167 0.041080       NA       NA      NA      NA      NA
5422      NA       NA 0.052223       NA       NA      NA      NA      NA
1286      NA       NA       NA       NA 0.019568      NA 0.31137 0.34364
1918      NA       NA       NA 0.026735       NA      NA      NA      NA
```

and in all cases the colnames of the dataframes starts out being, e.g:

```
> colnames(RelML)
[1] "AA" "BB" "CC" "DD" "EE" "LL" "MM" "NN"
```

And i the case of the RelML dataframe i want it to end up being:

```
> paste("ML",colnames(RelML),sep="")
[1] "MLAA" "MLBB" "MLCC" "MLDD" "MLEE" "MLLL" "MLMM" "MLNN"
```

I have tried fooling around with get(colnames(j)), colnames(as.name(j)) and more, but nothing seems to work. 
Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Regards Mads

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish in colnames(get(j))<-paste(i,colnames(get(j)),sep=""). Can you give an example of how the output should look like. Are "ML","HL" etc. individual data frames or column of a single dataframe

Comment: I have updated the post to make it clearer what i am requesting...hope it makes more sense

Comment: Are you trying to rename colnames of each dataframe as "dataframenamecolname"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thnik you're trying to accomplish this -

```
library(data.table)
for(i in c("ML","HL","MSMS","PEP","MqNormHM","MixHM","RawHM","AbsHM","SepAbsHM"))
      {
        j<-ifelse(i %in% c("ML","HL","MSMS","PEP","MqNormHM"),paste("Rel",i,sep=""),i)
        setnames(get(j), paste(i,colnames(get(j)),sep=""))
    }
```

The difference is only that I assign column names using `data.table::setnames`.

Comment: That work perfectly..Thank you very much!Any idea what the conceptual difference is between calling by get() within or without the data.frame package?

Comment: I don't know why the `get` doesn't work for sure, but when I use it, I usually use `get` only for reads and `assign` for writes. You could try that, if you're curious.

Comment: Oh, and `setnames` works by reference without creating a copy which is why it seems to work with `get`. The `colnames <- c()` creates a copy, I think, which probably messes around with the `get`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't `get` and object and modify its columns in one shot. You need to brake this into multiple statements to get, modify, and re-assign:

```
for (i in c("ML","HL","MSMS","PEP","MqNormHM",
            "MixHM","RawHM","AbsHM","SepAbsHM")) {
  j <- ifelse(i %in% c("ML","HL","MSMS","PEP","MqNormHM"),
              paste("Rel", i, sep = ""), i)
  o <- get(j)
  colnames(o) <- paste(i, colnames(o), sep = "")
  assign(j, o, envir = .GlobalEnv)
}
```

You can make all that vectorized and a little cleaner by doing:

```
z  <- c("ML","HL","MSMS","PEP","MqNormHM")
i  <- c("ML","HL","MSMS","PEP","MqNormHM","MixHM","RawHM","AbsHM","SepAbsHM")
j  <- ifelse(i %in% z, paste0("Rel", i), i)
o1 <- mget(j, envir = .GlobalEnv)
n1 <- lapply(o1, colnames)
n2 <- Map(paste0, i, n1)
o2 <- Map(`colnames<-`, o1, n2)

invisible(list2env(o2, .GlobalEnv))
```

Now the usual disclaimer: having to rely on `get/mget` and `assign` is usually a sign of a bad practice. Instead of having a lot of similar objects in your environment, you should be storing them into a list, then use `lapply` (and others) to process them all together.

Comment: That gives me: Error in mget(j) : argument "envir" is missing, with no default

Comment: try to add `envir = .GlobalEnv` to the `mget` call. (And it is high time you upgrade your R version :-)

Comment: That overcomes the mget error, but: > o2 <- mapply(`<-colnames`, o1, n2) gives me:
Error in match.fun(FUN) : object '<-colnames' not found

Comment: It should have been `colnames<-`. Fixed.